# How do I write the seat number and floor number in the US address format?

Tags: forms-of-address

Let us suppose that the building name where my office exists is ABC Center. Then, my office's street address is 1234 N ABC Rd, Washington, DC 12345. Then, my office is on the 4th floor. Then, the seat number is 111.

In this case, how can I express my address both in a single-line format and in a multi-line format?

For example,

> ABC Center, 1234 N ABC Rd, 4th floor, 111, Washington, DC 12345.

The above is correct????

Comment: What is a seat number? Do you mean like a room number? Like "4th Floor, Room 111"? Though I suppose the Postal Service website [Welcome | USPS](https://www.usps.com/) might be a better resource.

Comment: @user3169 On the 4th floor, there are many private rooms as well as many seats in the open area. My seat is in the open area and the number of seat is 111.

Comment: Because postal carriers do not deliver mail directly to your seat, seat or cubicle numbers are usually not included in a written address, so there is no standard format for this.

Comment: @CanadianYankee If 111 is the room number, how can I write it? Building name, then street address, then floor number, then room number, then city name, then state name and zip code. Is it correct?

Comment: It is not common to include both a floor number *and* a room number, because the room number usually defines the floor. In the US, usually you'd write "1234 N ABC Rd., Room 111" (which is most likely on the first floor, since it begins with 1).  But how offices are numbered varies a lot from company to company so, again, there is no standard format.

Comment: In the UK, we might include directions to the internal mail distribution staff of a building  (probably first) as well as directions (the 'postal address') to the postal carrier organisation, and UK addresses are split by lines, e.g. Mr D Kim/Room 111 4th Floor/Legal Tower North/27 High Street/Cambridge/CM1 2XX (the / characters are to show line endings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address is whatever magic words will get mail delivered to you.

Normally the first part of the address is your name. So something like

> Danny Kim, Seat 111, Floor 4
> ABC Center
> 1234 N ABC Rd
> Washington DC 12345

Should probably be enough information to find you. Generally, you put more specific information first.

However there is an easy way to check... talk to the person in seat 110 or 112 about the mail system in your building. It may be that mail is held centrally and you need to pick it up, so including a seat number is pointless (though it wouldn't cause the mail to be rejected)

Comment: I'd put "Danny Kim" on its own line at the top, then the seat/floor line second

Answer (score 1):

In the United States mail is delivered to the business only, including delivery to a specific suite in an office building. See [this FAQ page](https://faq.usps.com/s/article/What-are-some-Examples-of-How-to-Format-Different-Types-of-Addresses) listing example address formats. The room number of the recipient can be specified but this is usually informational in nature as far as the USPS is concerned—it is for the benefit of whatever person *within* the organization delivers mail internally.

You *may* be able to use some of the elements described as being for "business-to-business" use as defined in [USPS Publication 28](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c3_011.htm), such as the "Group/Department/Division Name" field, but this is not really meant to be used for seat-level addressing.

I would say that any granular addressing system should be put in the `ATTN:` line as described in the FAQ and will be specific to the company that uses it.